# Can I limit by unique count of a specific column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

Say that I have a database of songs.

```
ARTIST          |        SONG
-------------------------------------
Cloud Cult        The Meaning of 8
Cloud Cult        Pretty Voice
Jason Alexander   Today Was a Good Day
Jason Alexander   Like a Virgin
Jason Alexander   It Wasn't Me
Powderfinger      Like a Dog
```

What I want to do is issue a query that selects all the songs by a limit of 20 artists. Not just 20 database records, as many records as there are songs by those 20 artists. So in the above example, if I limited by 2, I would get 5 results, all the songs by Cloud Cult and all the songs by Jason Alexander.

Is this something SQL can do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a sub-query of Artists and `LIMIT` the sub-query by the number of required artists:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5406f/2)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`ARTIST` varchar(15), `SONG` varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`ARTIST`, `SONG`)
VALUES
    ('Cloud Cult', 'The Meaning of 8'),
    ('Cloud Cult', 'Pretty Voice'),
    ('Jason Alexander', 'Today Was a Good Day'),
    ('Jason Alexander', 'Like a Virgin'),
    ('Jason Alexander', 'It Wasn''t Me'),
    ('Powderfinger', 'Like a Dog')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t.* 
from (select distinct ARTIST from table1 LIMIT 2) a 
INNER JOIN table1 t on a.ARTIST = t.ARTIST
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5406f/2/0)**:

```
|          ARTIST |                 SONG |
|-----------------|----------------------|
|      Cloud Cult |     The Meaning of 8 |
|      Cloud Cult |         Pretty Voice |
| Jason Alexander | Today Was a Good Day |
| Jason Alexander |        Like a Virgin |
| Jason Alexander |         It Wasn't Me |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * FROM LibraryTable lt 
WHERE lt.artist IN (SELECT 
                    DISTINCT lt2.artist 
                    FROM LibraryTable lt2 LIMIT ***X***)
```

Where ***X*** is your artist limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by function to select specific data, here is the code

```
select table1.artist, table1.song from 
(select artist from table1
  group by artist limit 2) t1 
inner join table1 on t1.artist=table1.artist
```